# How to remove element from xml java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to remove a certain estrofe element from the xml, but how do I remove the element if it doesn't have a child, because the only remove function is removeChild(). Thank you for the help.

```
public boolean remove(short numEstrofe) {
    //System.out.println("Falta implementar!");
     NodeList list = D.getElementsByTagName("estrofe");

     for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
         if (i == numEstrofe) {
             Element estrofe = (Element) list.item(i);
             
             D.removeChild(estrofe);
             return true;
         }
     }
    return false;
}~
```

Here is the xml

```
<poema>
<autor>Luís de Camões</autor>
<título>Mudam-se os tempos, mudam-se as vontades</título>
<estrofe>
    <verso>Mudam-se os tempos, mudam-se as vontades,</verso>
    <verso>Muda-se o ser, muda-se a confiança;</verso>
    <verso>Todo o mundo é composto de mudança,</verso>
    <verso>Tomando sempre novas qualidades.</verso>
</estrofe>
<estrofe>
    <verso>Continuamente vemos novidades,</verso>
    <verso>Diferentes em tudo da esperança;</verso>
    <verso>Do mal ficam as mágoas na lembrança,</verso>
    <verso>E do bem, se algum houve, as saudades.</verso>
</estrofe>
<estrofe>
    <verso>O tempo cobre o chão de verde manto,</verso>
    <verso>Que já coberto foi de neve fria,</verso>
    <verso>E em mim converte em choro o doce canto.</verso>
</estrofe>
<estrofe>
    <verso>E, afora este mudar-se cada dia,</verso>
    <verso>Outra mudança faz de mor espanto:</verso>
    <verso>Que não se muda já como soía.</verso>
</estrofe>
</poema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Do not remove the element from a temporary nodelist - remove it from it's parent element instead.

```
Element estrofe = (Element) list.item(i);
estrofe.getParent().removeChild(estrofe);
```